# No module named 'encodings' on OpenSuse

Tags: python, opensuse, system-administration

A whole host of actions keep returning to this problem:

`pip install encodings`

`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

---

`python3`

`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

---

`libreoffice --safe-mode`

`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

---

`zypper se python |grep '^i '`

```
i  | libpython3_6m1_0                                         | Python Interpreter shared library                                                     | package
i  | libsamba-policy0-python3                                 | Active Directory Group Policy library                                                 | package
i  | python-qt3d-qt5-sip                                      | Sip files for python-qt3d-qt5                                                         | package
i  | python-qt5-utils                                         | Common files for PyQt5 for python2 and python3                                        | package
i  | python-qtdatavis3d-qt5-sip                               | Sip files for python-qtdatavis3d-qt5                                                  | package
i  | python-qtwebengine-qt5-sip                               | Sip files for python-qtwebengine-qt5                                                  | package
i  | python-rpm-generators                                    | Dependency generator dependencies for Python RPMs                                     | package
i  | python-rpm-macros                                        | RPM macros for building of Python modules                                             | package
i  | python-sip-common                                        | SIP tool to create python bindings -- common files                                    | package
i  | python-websockify-common                                 | Common data files for the Websockify TCP proxy/bridge                                 | package
i  | python3-Automat                                          | Self-service finite-state machines for the programmer on the go                       | package
i  | python3-Babel                                            | Internationalization utilities                                                        | package
i  | python3-Bottleneck                                       | A collection of fast NumPy array functions                                            | package
i  | python3-Brotli                                           | Python bindings for the Brotli compression library                                    | package
i  | python3-Cycler                                           | Composable style cycles                                                               | package
i  | python3-Cython                                           | The Cython compiler for writing C extensions for the Python language                  | package
i  | python3-Genshi                                           | A toolkit for generation of output for the web                                        | package
i  | python3-HeapDict                                         | A heap with decrease-key and increase-key operations                                  | package
i  | python3-Jinja2                                           | A fast and easy to use template engine written in pure Python                         | package
i  | python3-MarkupSafe                                       | Implements a XML/HTML/XHTML Markup safe string for Python                             | package
i  | python3-Pillow                                           | Python Imaging Library (Fork)                                                         | package
i  | python3-PyHamcrest                                       | Hamcrest framework for matcher objects                                                | package
i  | python3-PyJWT                                            | JSON Web Token implementation in Python                                               | package
i  | python3-PyNaCl                                           | Python binding to the Networking and Cryptography (NaCl) library                      | package
i  | python3-PySocks                                          | A Python SOCKS client module                                                          | package
i  | python3-PyWavelets                                       | PyWavelets is a Python wavelet transforms module                                      | package
i  | python3-PyYAML                                           | YAML parser and emitter for Python                                                    | package
i  | python3-Pygments                                         | A syntax highlighting package written in Python                                       | package
i  | python3-QtPy                                             | Abstraction layer on top of Qt bindings                                               | package
i  | python3-SQLAlchemy                                       | Database Abstraction Library                                                          | package
etc...
```

I think I've only got python 3.6 installed but the only suggestion I've seen is where there is more than one  version installed.

## Any suggestions on what I should test now to find the source of this problem?

My Env:

---

`uname -a`

`Linux localhost.localdomain 5.3.18-150300.59.49-preempt #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 7 14:40:20 UTC 2022 (77d9d02) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

---

`python`

`-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`

---

`python3`

`Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep 23 2021, 15:41:43) [GCC] on linux`

`Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

`>>>` (then exited from python console)

---

`echo $PYTHONHOME` returns nothing

`echo $PYTHONPATH` returns nothing

---

I have subsequently reinstalled the OS with no different result (surprising to me) and I've tried `strace -o pythonstrace.txt python3.6` The (presumably) relevant part of the strace output is:

```
munmap(0x7f780442e000, 262144)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f780442e000
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x7), ...}) = 0
stat("/sbin/python3.6", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/python3.6", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/python3.6", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/root/bin/python3.6", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/python3.6", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/python3.6", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10472, ...}) = 0
readlink("/usr/bin/python3.6", 0x7ffff6517fa0, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/pyvenv.cfg", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/pyvenv.cfg", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/Modules/Setup", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/lib64/python3.6/os.py", 0x7ffff6518f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/lib64/python3.6/os.pyc", 0x7ffff6518f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37526, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/pybuilddir.txt", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload", 0x7ffff6521070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4802, ...}) = 0
brk(0x55a4968ff000)                     = 0x55a4968ff000
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78043ee000
sysinfo({uptime=132115, loads=[4256, 3872, 448], totalram=16583553024, freeram=1984724992, sharedram=68530176, bufferram=122511360, totalswap=2146430976, freeswap=2146430976, procs=990, totalhigh=0, freehigh=0, mem_unit=1}) = 0
brk(0x55a496921000)                     = 0x55a496921000
sigaltstack({ss_sp=0x55a4968d9c20, ss_flags=0, ss_size=8192}, {ss_sp=NULL, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=0}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python36.zip", 0x7ffff6529bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=10808, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python36.zip", 0x7ffff65293b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4054, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4054, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4054, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/python3.6", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4054, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 204 entries */, 32768) = 6800
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__init__.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so", 0x7ffff65296f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__init__.abi3.so", 0x7ffff65296f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__init__.so", 0x7ffff65296f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__init__.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5642, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78043ae000
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__init__.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5642, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3922, ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3922, ...}) = 0
read(3, "3\r\r\n@*\273a\n\26\0\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0@\0\0"..., 3923) = 3922
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4054, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/codecs.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36276, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/codecs.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36276, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-36.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=33902, ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=33902, ...}) = 0
read(3, "3\r\r\n@*\273a\264\215\0\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0:\0\0\0@\0\0"..., 33903) = 33902
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=2708, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=2708, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=2708, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=2708, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 128 entries */, 32768) = 4336
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/aliases.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=15577, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/aliases.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=15577, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-36.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6266, ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6266, ...}) = 0
read(3, "3\r\r\n@*\273a\331<\0\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D\1\0\0@\0\0"..., 6267) = 6266
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=2708, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1005, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1005, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-36.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1584, ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
```

This seems to show that it can't find a whole bunch of files, from a variety of different directories and they're not even even all in a common directory branch! a selection of examples: `/sbin/python3.6`, `/usr/sbin/python3.6`, `/usr/local/sbin/python3.6`, `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`, `/usr/lib64/python3.6`

Just also tried from my home bash prompt:

```
me@myhost:~> python
ImportError: No module named site
me@myhost:~> python2
ImportError: No module named site
me@myhost:~> python2.7
ImportError: No module named site
me@myhost:~> python3
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f5e446c0740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
me@myhost:~> python3.6
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f0e8c018740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
greg@TRANQUILITY:~>
```

And as root:

```
HOST:~ # python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar 04 2021, 23:25:57) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[2]+  Stopped                 python
HOST:~ # python2
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar 04 2021, 23:25:57) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[3]+  Stopped                 python2
HOST:~ # python2.7
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar 04 2021, 23:25:57) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[4]+  Stopped                 python2.7
HOST:~ # python3
Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep 23 2021, 15:41:43) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[5]+  Stopped                 python3
HOST:~ # python3.6
Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep 23 2021, 15:41:43) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I checked `env` and added `export LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8` to ~/.bashrc (mine, not root's) - made no difference from a new terminal

I also used 'strace python3.6`as both me and root and saved the output to two files and then in VSCode diffed them. I don't have the tech knowledge to make sense of it but the 'root' strace is much longer and works, the 'greg' strace is shorter and on line 216, says`write(2, "No module named 'encodings'", 27No module named 'encodings') = 27`

As greg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p55uen19njil5zb/stracePython3.6-greg.lua?dl=0

As root
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlxu43yeqnb7li2/stracePython3.6-root.lua?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `strace` output for both `root` and `greg`, the problem seems clear.

For the `root` user, python 3.6 finds the libraries in `/usr/lib64/python3.6`.

However, for `greg`, it only looks under `/usr/bin/python3` for subdirectories. That doesn't work because `/usr/bin/python3` is a file.

I suspect that the user `greg` has `PYTOHNHOME` set erroneously to the location of the Python binary , and that is causing the issue.

**Remove `PYTOHNHOME` from your environment, log out and log in again.**

Note: the stuff below is probably barking up the wrong tree. I'll leave it for information.

---

The `encodings` module is an (undocumented) part of the python standard library. It is used by the `locale` module.

Based on the output I suspect that your  Python installation has been damaged or corrupted. Try re-installing python.

**EDIT**:

If a forced re-install doesn't fix the problem, check that the directory `encodings` exist in your Python stdlib directory, and is accessible for all users.

To find out which directory that is:

```
python
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')
'/usr/local/lib/python3.9'
```

Check accessability:

```
ls -ld /usr/local/lib/python3.9/encodings
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  5632 Dec 11 14:34 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/encodings/
```

Read and execute for all users, so that is OK.

**EDIT2:**

Looking at the trace results.

I don't think the missing files are something to worry about. That's just Python looking for the different locations/names that files can have, given that Python is a multiplatform program.

The interesting bit is near the end:

```
stat("/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__init__.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5642, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78043ae000
```

This shows that it *can* find the directory, and map `__init__.py` into memory.

**EDIT3:**

Since both Python 2.7 and 3.6 are end-of-life now, I would suggest removing them, and install python 3.10 instead.

**EDIT4:**

The directory structure is determined by how you install Python. WRT permissions, directories usually have permissions 0755 and files 0644. Traditionally on UNIX, files in `/usr/` are owned by `root`, while the group differs among systems.
The last number (permission for "others" being neither the owner nor the group) are probably most relevant.

You can fix permissions with a combination of `find` and `chmod`. For example:

```
find /usr/lib64/python3.6 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /usr/lib64/python3.6 -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

should set a good set of permissions for both files and directories in the Python tree.

Comment: I've done the following since posting:

1/ `zypper rm python2.7`

2/ I started to uninstall python completely, before a single version reinstall but it looked like it would have to uninstall large sections of the UI etc which looked very scary, so I didn't and instead did 

3/ `zypper in -f python3.6`

1 & 3 didn't fix the problem. Do you suggest going for 2? (Or an OS refresh - currently on OpenSUse Leap 15.3)?

Comment: @Greg See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Roland-smith
`localhost:~ # python3`
`Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep 23 2021, 15:41:43) [GCC] on linux`
`Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`
`>>> import sysconfig`
`>>> sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')`
`'/usr/lib64/python3.6'`
---
`localhost:~ # ls -ld /usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings`
`drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2708 Jan 12 00:47 /usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings`
---
Does that look right? It's certainly got read and execute authority for all users

Comment: Note that I can only access the Python console as root. As me I get the encodings error

Comment: At least the folder exists, and the permissions look OK. But it's weird that it only works as root. Try using `find` or `locate` with "bin/python3." to check if you maybe have multiple Python installations lying around. And check for compiled files in `__pycache__` folders with weird permissions.

Comment: I decided to try the *reinstall the OS* route but am now stuck in a RAID1 GPT table corruption that's stopping me doing anything, so I can't respond to this thread until I've fixed that issue. Sorry - just keeping this thread up-to-date on why no resolution.

Comment: Well, if your RAID is b0rked, that might have been the problem all along.

Comment: I fixed the GPT error and recovered my RAID, and reinstalled my OS. It's made little difference.  `echo $PYTHONHOME`  which returns `/usr/bin/python3`.  `/usr/bin` contains a bunch of python executables and configs but there's no `python3` subdirectory. Guessing this is the nub of the problem but stumped on a) why it's like this and b) what I can do about it?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `PYTHONHOME:` *change the location of the standard Python libraries.* In general, you do not want to do this. Remove it from your environment.

Comment: Another thread suggested `strace python3.6` (2.7 & 3.6 seem to be present, post OS refresh).

I'll add the (probably)relevant part of the `strace` to the original post

Comment: @Greg See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. I've added the rest of the `strace` from the line you thought was interesting. I'm way out of my depth at this point, as I've no idea how to interpret the `strace` output!

Comment: Also: 
`ls -ld /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings`
`drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8328 Mar  7 23:32 /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings`

Comment: Thanks @Roland but OpenSuse doesn't have 3.10 in their repo yet (nor, seemingly does the Packman repo) - I'm on OpenSuse Leap 15.3

Comment: Then whatever most modern Python is available.

Comment: 3.6 is the latest :(

Comment: Then it's probably time to switch to a different distro...

Comment: I realise my reluctance to do that (I like Open Suse/KDE/Plasma5) may mean you won't continue to respond but I have one last request. Are you aware of where to find documentation that specifies the directory/file topology and permissions. Python works for root but not regular users, so I'm still inclined to think this is a file and/or folder permissions problem. Reinstallation hasn't had any effect, so I also think that if it is permissions, it's somewhere in my home directory, which wasn't changed by my OS refresh

Comment: See updated answer (edit4). Your home directory permissions shouldn't affect the readability of files in `/usr/lib64`.

Comment: I did as you suggested in Edit 4 but no luck. However, I did try `python3.6 -v`, which as root continued to a working python console but as me b0rked at this line`# installing zipimport hook
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
`

Comment: What are your locale settings, for both the normal user and root? (try `env|grep LC_`) Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: me: no/null response, but root: `LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8`

Comment: Set LC_ALL to en_GB.UTF-8 for your user account. On FreeBSD I would do that in /etc/login.conf, but I can't recall how Linux does that.

Comment: BTW, I've added `export LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8` and `export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8` to ~/.bashrc. After saving I opened a new terminal and `python3.6` still had the same problem.  

I have added Dropbox links to the full (root) working and (greg) not-working strace output in to the main question

Comment: @Greg See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your insight and patience @Roland. As you suggested, I (?) had set PYTHONHOME in my `~/.profile`; which is, I think the OpenSuse equivalent of `~/.bashprofile`. It seems to be working now though - great relief!